# fcntl() for thread or process synchronization?

Tags: c++, c, synchronization, semaphore, fcntl

Is it possible to use fcntl() system call on a file to achieve thread/process synchronization (instead of semaphoress)?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Some more information about what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Unix fcntl locks (and filesystem resources in general) are system-wide, so any two threads of execution (be they separate processes or not) can use them.  Whether that's a good idea or not is context-dependent.

Comment: Thanks, my question was not whether I want to do this but whether its possible. And it turned out that yes its possible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

That's one way of synchronizing between processes, but if you don't want to use semaphores, you could use process shared mutexes, such as mutexes and condition variables created with the `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` attribute on POSIX based platforms (see [`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989799/xsh/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html) and [`pthread_condattr_setpshared()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989799/xsh/pthread_condattr_setpshared.html)).  Another option is to use an event based IPC (sockets, etc) mechanism that blocks until an event you define is demultiplexed (e.g. via [`select()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/select.html)).  There are several other shared memory based options as well.

However, since you're using C++ I'd recommend using a C++ framework that greatly simplifies this sort of interprocess synchronization across multiple platforms like [boost.interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) or [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html).

Answer (score -1):

The fcntl and flock are not for thread, but for process, so they cannot be used for thread synchronization.

Comment: fcntl has multi-thread false dead-lock checking (design defect). Think about such scenario, two processes which both have two threads. The thread 1 look like: for(;;) {fcntl_auto_lock(file1);}. The thread 2 look like: for(;;) {fcntl_auto_lock(file2);}. The fcntl would return EDEADLK(35)
Here can find more details: 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62457#c5