# Shared mmap co-ordination using fcntl locks?

Tags: python, synchronization, shared-memory, mmap, fcntl

When using `mmap()` for shared memory (from Linux, or other UNIX-like systems) is it possible (and portable) to use `fcntl()` (or `flock()` or `lockf()` functions) to co-ordinate access to the mapping?

Responses to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765301/fcntl-for-thread-or-process-synchronization) seems to suggest that it should work.

The idea I have in mind would be to have the shared memory structured with a process/page map to minimize the locking contention.  Processes could each work with their pages concurrently, and a lock would only need to be acquired when updating the process/page mappings.  (Read access from unowned pages would involve checking a serial number, copying the desired data, then validating that the serial number of that block hadn't changed).

Conceptually each process sharing this file mapping would perform the `mmap()`, find a free block therein,  acquire a lock to the process/page area, update that with its own assignment, release the lock and then go on merrily with its work.  Any process could search for stale mappings (using `kill()` with zero as the signal) and clean up the process/page table mapping.

(In rough, generic terms, I'm toying with a producer/consumer processing engine using shared memory from Python over Linux; I'd like the solution to be portable to BSD and to other programming languages --- so long as the support `mmap()` and the necessary interfaces to `fcntl()`, `flock()` or `lockf().`  I'd also be interested in psuedo-code showing how one would measure lock contention and detect any synchronization failures.  I am aware that the *threading* and *multiprocessing* with their respective `Queue()` objects are the most straightforward way to implement a Python producer/consumer processing model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the locks will provide mutual exclusion, but I don't know if they will give you a memory barrier.  It seems like jumping into the kernel (which fcntl, flock, and lockf will do) is likely to do *something* that forces out of order memory reads and writes to commit, but I doubt you'll get a hard guarantee.  I think this is one of those things where it probably works, and testing will show that it does work, but you won't know that it always works unless you find a reference saying as much.

I've done something similar to this from C, but I used atomic spinlocks in the shared memory itself.  It used to be that you had to do a little bit of inline assembly, but gcc now has some intrinsic operations that you can use:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

If you're willing to write a very simple Python extension, you could wrap __sync_lock_test_and_set(...) and __sync_lock_release(...) to do what you need.  Those should be pretty portable.

I believe there is a way to put pthread mutexes into shared memory too, but I don't have any experience with that.  Again, you'd have to write a simple C extension to get access to that from Python.

Comment: No need to write a Python extension actually. You can use Python's `ctypes` module to tap into the C library directly via Python code. (You still need a fair amount of knowledge about C though)